# extracting integer's data into my txt file With Clojure

Tags: clojure

I'm new with  clojure, and i want extracting the data (only the integer numbers) in txt file for a differents processing.

in the first time i want to extract the integer data which are on the txt file  :
         `({score 1} {:score 2} {:score 3} {:score 4} {:score 5} {:score 6}    {:score 7} {:score 8} {:score 9} {:score 10} {:score 11} {:score 12} {:score 13} {:score 14} {:score 11} {:score 12} {:score 13} {:score 14} {:score 15} {:score 16} {:score 17} {:score 18} {:score 19} {:score 20} {:score 21} {:score 22} {:score 23} {:score 24} {:score 11} {:score 2} {:score 3} {:score 5} {:score 8} {:score 4} {:score 5} {:score 2} {:score 2} {:score 8} {:score 4} {:score 7} {:score 5} {:score 2} {:score 5} {:score 5} {:score 2} {:score 6} {:score 2} {:score 5} {:score 2} {:score 3} {:score 5} {:score 2} {:score 3} {:score 5} {:score 23} {:score 5} {:score 7} {:score 7} {:score 7} {:score 7} {:score 7} {:score 7} {:score 7} {:score 7} {:score 7} {:score 7} {:score 7} {:score 7} {:score 7} {:score 7} {:score 0} {:score 0} {:score 0} {:score 0} {:score 0} {:score 0} {:score 0} {:score 0}`

after this i want to extract  a data on another file txt for apply the the differents opération between all of data .

the second txt file is like :

```
   `  <  name 1>: <45>   <name 2 >: <78>     <  name 3>: <100>  <name 4 >: <8> `
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a solution for your second problem (which is really unrelated to your first which was nicely formated as EDN values).

For this sample (foo.txt):

```
<foo 1>: <45> <bar 2>: <78> <baz 3>: <100> <qux 4>: <8>
```

The following creates a map of the names to values:

```
(defn data-to-map [f]
  (reduce (fn [acc i] 
            (assoc acc (nth i 1) (nth i 2)))
          {} 
          (re-seq #"<([^>]+)>: <([^>]+)>" (slurp f))))
```

It uses a regex to break up your pattern into `<some name>:` `<some value>` and puts them in a map using the name as key.

Note, in your question you place the colon right next to the close bracket, if there are spaces (as in your comments to @piyushmandovra) then you'll have to adjust the regex to suit with additional `\s` whitespace values.

Example repl output:

```
user> (data-to-map "foo.txt")
{"qux 4" "8", "baz 3" "100", "bar 2" "78", "foo 1" "45"}
```

If you only want values, and not names from your second sample (not sure why, but that's what you originally asked for)

```
(defn data-vals-to-array [f] 
  (reduce (fn [acc i] 
            (conj acc (nth i 2)))
          []
          (re-seq #"<([^>]+)>: <([^>]+)>" (slurp f))))
```

with example

```
user> (data-vals-to-array "foo.txt")
["45" "78" "100" "8"]
```

In this case, it discards the name and just `conj`s the data into the vector.

You could replace the reducing function to simply `#(conj %1 (last %2))` but I kept it similar to the map example for clarity.

I've kept everything as strings for simplicity. If your data is good enough, parse the integers using [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5621279/in-clojure-how-can-i-convert-a-string-to-a-number)

Comment: Thank you very much for your ansewers , these is all what i'm checked  !!! Tahnks

Answer (score 1):

if I am correct you need data like :

```
(1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 11)
```

if so then your solution is right here

```
(map :score (read-string(slurp "file-location")))
```

Comment: thank you for your response , exactly it's what i nedd .. but when i try to apply it in another format i have an error , the format is like :
        `< name > : < 25 > < name > : < 30 > < name > : < 5 > < name > : < 15 >`

i'm using this syntax : (map :< (read-string(slurp "file-location")))

can you tell me where is a probleme in my function ?

Comment: please provide me exact data so i can help you..?

Comment: that is mean i can't read a string on another format , like my second file txt ?

Comment: and if i'm  right , can'i covert my txt file to a edn file ? i'm sorry for these a lots of questions by i need to resolve a probleme today

Comment: dude check here http://conj.io/ all clojure higher order function here.
hope it will help, if i will come up with soln will update.