# Clojure edit value of vector within function

Tags: clojure

I have the variable cards with empty values:

```
(def cards [0 0 0])
```

Im trying to set a value of cards (depending on input) to a 3 within a function.
Thats why i have the following code:

```
(defn parse-int [s]
  (Integer. (re-find  #"\d+" s )))

(defn changevalue [] (assoc cards (parse-int (read-line)) 3)) 
(changevalue)
```

But when i execute the problem and typ in my input 1, the function doesn't change the value of key 1, and when i print it, its still 0 0 0 . How do I fix this?

Im sure the parse-int works, i got it from: [In Clojure how can I convert a String to a number?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5621279/in-clojure-how-can-i-convert-a-string-to-a-number)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firstly, just use `Integer/parseInt` to parse the input:

```
(defn change-value [cards]
  (let [s (read-line)]
    (assoc cards (Integer/parseInt s) 3)))
```

This function returns a **copy** of `cards`, with one of its elements changed. Remember, `cards` is a vector, which is immutable.
 You can't change it once it's been created.

You wrote "the function doesn't change the value of key 1, and when i print it, its still 0 0 0 . How do I fix this?" You don't fix it, you embrace immutability. Don't try to change `cards`. Use the modified copy that `change-value` returns:

```
(def cards [0 0 0])
(def changed-cards (change-value cards))

(println cards)
(println changed-cards)
```

If you really, *really*, **really** need mutability, you can use an `atom`, but that shouldn't be your first option. Clojure is a functional language with heavy emphasis on immutability. Go with the flow instead of trying to fight the language.

Comment: How do i make the function "change-value" return the new cards?

Comment: @Jelle The function I posted does. Remember, the last form in the function is automatically returned. Try running all the code I posted.

Answer (score 1):

Clojure's data structure is almost immutable.
In clojure, substitution for mutating values is restricted strictly.
If you want mutable data structure, you can use Java's mutable data structure or clojure's {atom,ref,var}.

If you truly want to mutate cards, try do this:

```
(def cards (atom [0 0 0]))
(defn change-cards! [idx] (swap! cards assoc idx 3))
(change-cards! 2)
@cards
#_"here is no parseint to simplify your problem"
```