# Converting Integer to Long

Tags: java, reflection, casting

I need to get the value of a field using reflection. It so happens that I am not always sure what the datatype of the field is. For that, and to avoid some code duplication I have created the following method:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
private static <T> T getValueByReflection(VarInfo var, Class<?> classUnderTest, Object runtimeInstance) throws Throwable {
  Field f = classUnderTest.getDeclaredField(processFieldName(var));
  f.setAccessible(true);
  T value = (T) f.get(runtimeInstance);

  return value;
}
```

And use this method like:

```
Long value1 = getValueByReflection(inv.var1(), classUnderTest, runtimeInstance);
```

or

```
Double[] value2 = getValueByReflection(inv.var2(), classUnderTest, runtimeInstance);
```

The problem is that I can't seem to cast `Integer` to `Long`:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to java.lang.Long
```

Is there a better way to achieve this?

I am using Java 1.6.

Answer (score 108, accepted):

No, you can't cast `Integer` to `Long`, even though you can convert from `int` to `long`. For an *individual* value which is known to be a number and you want to get the long value, you could use:

```
Number tmp = getValueByReflection(inv.var1(), classUnderTest, runtimeInstance);
Long value1 = tmp.longValue();
```

For arrays, it will be trickier...

Comment: For arrays I can use a `Number[]` and a loop over it to create an appropriately typed array, right?

Comment: @Tiago: It depends on what the method's *actually* returning. That wouldn't work for a `double[]` for example, but *would* work for a `Double[]`.

Comment: Why can't you cast from an Integer to a Long?

Comment: @MrMas: Because they're separate reference types, both direct subclasses of `Number`. Or to put it another way: which conversion rule do you believe *does* let you convert from one to the other?

Comment: Ok. The problem is inheritance. I'm thinking in terms of precision. An integer can be converted to a long integer without losing information. But the inheritance structure doesn't have any information that would tell the compiler that.

Answer (score 158):

Simply:

```
Integer i = 7;
Long l = new Long(i);
```

Comment: NPE is thrown if the Integer is null

Comment: Works for `int` values.

Comment: Long.valueof should be used: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2974561/new-integer-vs-valueof

Comment: This code works (Java implicitly unboxes the `Integer` to `int` and then casts to `long` before passing to the now deprecated `Long(long)` constructor.

Comment: `new Long` is deprecated

Answer (score 76):

```
Integer i = 5; //example

Long l = Long.valueOf(i.longValue());
```

This avoids the performance hit of converting to a String. The `longValue()` method in Integer is just a cast of the int value. The `Long.valueOf()` method gives the vm a chance to use a cached value.

Comment: To be null save: Long l = i == null ? null : i.longValue()

Answer (score 21):

Oddly enough I found that if you parse from a string it works.

```
 int i = 0;
 Long l = Long.parseLong(String.valueOf(i));
 int back = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(l));
```

Win.

Comment: It makes absolutely no sense for me, but it works like a charm. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Introducing a string conversion for no reason is a really bad idea... there's simply no benefit in doing this.

Comment: Agree with @JonSkeet, better off with this:Object i = 10;Long l = ((Number) i).longValue();

Comment: This method works fine but is relatively slow and uses more memory than the other methods of doing this...

Comment: looks great from a front end developer perspective

Answer (score 13):

If the Integer is not null

```
Integer i;
Long long = Long.valueOf(i);
```

`i` will be automatically typecast to a `long`.

Using `valueOf` instead of `new` allows caching of this value (if its small) by the compiler or JVM , resulting in faster code.

Comment: I can't find a Long.valueOf(Integer i) method, the only ones I find are valueOf(long l), valueOf(String s) and valueOf(String s, int radix). Checked for Java8 and Java9 docs.

Comment: Integer is implicitly converted to a primitive long type.

Answer (score 10):

Converting Integer to Long Very Simple and many ways to converting that
Example 1

```
 new Long(your_integer);
```

Example 2

```
Long.valueOf(your_integer);
```

Example 3

```
Long a = 12345L;
```

Example 4
   If you already have the int typed as an Integer you can do this:

```
Integer y = 12;
long x = y.longValue();
```

Answer (score 6):

Convert an integer directly to long by adding 'L' to the end of Integer.

```
Long i = 1234L;
```

Comment: I am sure you have answered without reading the entire question!

Comment: @Diablo this question is the first result when searching "int to long" on Google, this answer may be useful to others

Comment: @DimitriW I am not saying this answer is wrong, But I am saying the answer for this question is wrong. You are right,This is useful for those people who doesn't read the question and look at the answer only.

Answer (score 5):

```
((Number) intOrLongOrSomewhat).longValue()
```

Answer (score 2):

If you know that the Integer is not NULL, you can simply do this:

```
Integer intVal = 1;
Long longVal = (long) (int) intVal
```

Answer (score 2):

```
new Long(Integer.longValue());
```

or

```
new Long(Integer.toString());
```

Answer (score 2):

If you don't know the exact class of your number (*Integer*, *Long*, *Double*, whatever), you can cast to *Number* and get your long value from it:

```
Object num = new Integer(6);
Long longValue = ((Number) num).longValue();
```

Answer (score 1):

A parser from `int` variables to the `long` type is included in the `Integer` class. Here is an example:

```
int n=10;
long n_long=Integer.toUnsignedLong(n);
```

You can easily use this in-built function to create a method that parses from `int` to `long`:

```
    public static long toLong(int i){
    long l;
    if (i<0){
        l=-Integer.toUnsignedLong(Math.abs(i));
    }
    else{
        l=Integer.toUnsignedLong(i);
    }
    return l;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For a nullable wrapper instance,

```java
Integer i;
Long l = Optional.ofNullable(i)
                 .map(Long::valueOf)
                 .orElse(null);
```

Answer (score 1):

To convert Integer into Long simply cast the Integer value

```java
Integer intValue = 23;
Long longValue = (long) intValue;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is null-safe

```
Number tmp = getValueByReflection(inv.var1(), classUnderTest, runtimeInstance);
Long value1 = tmp == null ? null : tmp.longValue();
```

Answer (score -3):

In case of a List of type Long,  Adding L to end of each Integer value

```
List<Long> list = new ArrayList<Long>();
list  = Arrays.asList(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L);
```

Answer (score -4):

Try to convertValue by Jackson

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper()
Integer a = 1;
Long b = mapper.convertValue(a, Long.class)
```

Comment: This is definitely not the best answer: this solution adds unnecessary complexity, performance overhead and requires an extra library (Jackson)