# Is it possible to convert ArrayList<Integer> into ArrayList<Long>?

Tags: java, arraylist

In my application I want to convert an `ArrayList` of `Integer` objects into an `ArrayList` of `Long` objects. Is it possible?

Comment: You can't do it directly. Maybe this post could help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6690745/converting-integer-to-long

Comment: Ohhhh guyes. Why are you voting down this question?

Comment: It's not clear what you are exactly asking. You have to demonstrate it with some code.

Comment: The question is pretty clear, however it does not demonstrate any effort. With common questions such as this, you will typically get less down votes if you include *what* you have tried - and the results.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Not in a 1 liner.

```
List<Integer> ints = Arrays.asList(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9);
int nInts = ints.size();
List<Long> longs = new ArrayList<Long>(nInts);
for (int i=0;i<nInts;++i) {
    longs.add(ints.get(i).longValue());
}
```

// Or you can use Lambda expression in Java 8

```
List<Integer> ints = Arrays.asList(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9);
List<Long> longs = ints.stream()
        .mapToLong(Integer::longValue)
        .boxed().collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Brilliant!!! I was not able to convert it without your answer!
Thank you very much!

Comment: Could anybody please give a hint, why is the boxed() method used in the second example? Since it's been worked here not with primitive 'int' values...

Answer (score 6):

No, you can't because, generics are not polymorphic.I.e., `ArrayList<Integer>` is not a subtype of `ArrayList<Long>`, thus the cast will fail.
Thus, the only way is to Iterate over your `List<Integer>` and add it in `List<Long>`.

```
List<Long> longList = new ArrayList<Long>();
for(Integer i: intList){
longList.add(i.longValue());
}
```

Comment: Thanks! But this is not working!

Comment: Sorry! now i have selected the correct answer

Answer (score 0):

```
ArrayList<Long> longList = new ArrayList<Long>();

Iterator<Integer> it = intList.iterator();
while(it.hasNext())
{
    Integer obj = it.next();
    longList.add(obj); //will automatically convert Int to Long
}
```

Done....

Comment: This doesn't even compile because these object types don't convert automatically. `longList.add((long)obj);` or any of the other solutions would work.