# Java Reflection: Casting an Object to another without knowing their types

Tags: java, reflection, casting, resultset

I am using reflections to map an `ResultSet` to a `Field` in bean.

```
field = clazz.getDeclaredField(str);
field.setAccessible(true);
Object resultSetObject = rs.getObject(str);
Class fieldType = field.getType();
field.set(clazzInst, fieldType.cast(resultSetObject));
```

The problem is `resultSetObject` is of type `Integer` and `fieldType` is of Long and I cannot cast Intger to Long and getting `ClassCastException`.

Comment: This question might help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6690745/converting-integer-to-long

Comment: In that question you explicitly know that you have to cast Integer to Long, but here i don't know about their types

Comment: Casting doesn't do anything to the type of the object.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis will you please elaborate on this?

Comment: *Why* is the ResultSet-derived object of type Integer while the target field is of type Long? (NB I suspect it's actually the other way around.) The ***real*** solution here is to make sure your Java and SQL data models match.

Answer (score 0):

You are essentially asking to duplicate the type knowledge that is available at compile-time with which the compiler generates the correct conversion.  The runtime doesn't have this knowledge, so you will have to provide it by building a matrix of types and coding all the conversions you want, explicitly.

You can define this as a matrix indexed by type along both axes (from-type and to-type) or more likely as a Map whose key is a `ConversionType` object each instance of which defines `fromType`, `toType` and a `convert()` method.

Answer (score 0):

Whether you have

```
Object ref = new String("object of type string");
```

or

```
String ref = new String("still object of type string");
```

the object referenced will be of type `String`. Doing

```
Object obj = (Object) new String("still a string");
```

does not change that the referenced object is a `String`. In your case, you'll probably need a conversion strategy to convert between types.

Comment: that is interesting, yet could you please share your source so I can learn more? thank you

Comment: @kick I don't have any right now. You have to differentiate between instances, references and variables.

Answer (score 0):

You still have another option, convert long to string ,and then convert to integer.

Comment: But since I don't know their types explicitly, I must be prepared for the cases where fieldType and resultSetObject can be of different Types like Date, int, Double Boolean or any other types

Comment: You don't know the exact data type in your database? You can read it from database MetaData.

Comment: I can do that but then I have to define a conversion strategy from every possible type to every other types

Comment: NO ,YOU ONLY NEED TO DEFINE THE CONVERSION RULE BETWEEN YOUR TYPE WITH STRING.

Comment: but why? don't I have to convert string to myType again?