# Long and Integer class cast

Tags: java, casting, int, long-integer

I have simple question. I already know that in Java you can't do sth like:

`Long.class.cast(and Integer here)`

but I am just curious why? In the opposite way you can easily get into overflow, but this way I can't find anything bad which can happen.
Can anyone tell me what is wrong in using casting that way?

EDIT->

So what I am trying to do. I have already wrote a converter which converts me from my provided input(it is a Map) to my model. I wanted to write 1 converter for every model which I specify. Currently, it works for objects inside it(such as other models which I provided), strings, and the same types(for example I have got an integer and I provide an integer). What I am trying to do, I want to 'update' my converter to work in such cases like: in my model I have a field of type Long, and I provided Integer. So I want it to convert Integer to Long, however, I don't want to make if only for that case(because in such situation for example converting from Short to Long would be another if). Is it possible?

Comment: `Integer integer = 1;
        System.out.println(Long.class.cast(integer)); `
It throws exception, and I am just wondering why

Comment: it is just done different way: `Long l = new Long(10i);`

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels [Class#cast(Object)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#cast-java.lang.Object-)).

Comment: @Dukeling: thank you for that

Comment: @Ajris What are you trying to do? Based on [your comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51919763/long-and-integer-class-cast#comment90789481_51919803) it looks like you are trying to do something else. This is known as a "XY problem", so you might want to write something about your "X" problem.

Comment: I updated whole question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Converting Integer to Long](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6690745)

Answer (score 2):

Because `Object.cast(Object obj)` is not just for numbers. It's used for type convertion.

`ClassCastException` will be throws if the object is not null and is not assignable to the type Long.

You can just use this:

```
Integer integer = 1;

Long l = integer.longValue();
```

---

Or you can call `longValue` on `Long` or `Integer`, then use `Long.class.cast`:

```
Integer integer = 1;
Long longType = 1L;

Long l = Long.class.cast(longType.longValue());
l = Long.class.cast(integer.longValue());
```

Comment: Yea, but when I use reflection and I don't want to use ifs for casting integer to long, is it possible to do it another way?

Comment: `(long) yourInt` maybe.. `Ex: (long) 2`

Comment: I don't want to use ifs, co for example if I use casting, it works for converting some of my classes to another ones. And if I provide integer, it wouldn't convert it to long because of this exception. And I don't want to check every time whether I provided integer or another type, just want to have one solution which also works for Integer and Long. Is it possible?

Comment: @Ajris An `int` value can be assigned to a `long` variable without (explicit) casting. Using primitives would probably be better, unless you have a specific need to use classes (or your input is an `Object`).

Comment: Your update still doesn't help as It requires if statement for integer.(check question update)

Comment: @Ajris Every [`Number`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Number.html) subclass (`Long`, `Integer`, `Short`, `Byte`, etc.) has a `longValue` method - you shouldn't need an if-statement for `Integer` specifically.

Comment: I'd suggest removing the second part of your answer. `Long.class.cast` is a no-op (i.e. it does nothing) in those cases, because the input is already an (autoboxed) `Long` (the first part of your answer does the same just without the `cast`).

Comment: Hmmm, all right, so the only if that I have to write is about checking whether Number class is assignable from my object type right? And then just convert it using TYPEvalue method

Comment: @Ajris Yes, probably.