# Java Swing Error

Tags: java, swing

I've been given a practical to do, and it comes with a ImageEditor file which I can show if needed however it's lengthy so I've not posted it on here.

I have to implement a save link and have been given the code which I have stored in a separate class file:

```
public class SaveAction extends AbstractAction{
    public SaveAction(String text, ImageIcon icon, String desc, Integer mnemonic){
        super(text, icon);
        putValue(SHORT_DESCRIPTION, desc);
        putValue(MNEMONIC_KEY, mnemonic);
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
       // Just print out a message for now.
       System.out.println("Save");
   }
}
```

And then creating an instance in the main class:

```
Action saveAction = new SaveAction(
    "Save", new ImageIcon("img/save.png"), "Save the image", KeyEvent.VK_S);
```

However it is coming up with the error:

> The Constructor SaveAction(String, ImageIcon, String, int) is
>   undefined.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Perhaps: int mnemonic, in the parameters?

Comment: It specifies `Integer`  but is passed an `int`.  I am surprised auto-boxing does not take care of that.

Comment: It does. Must be old version of Java.

Answer (score 3):

You have the constructor as:

```
public SaveAction(String text, ImageIcon icon, String desc, Integer mnemonic)
```

and you are calling :

```
new SaveAction("Save", new ImageIcon("img/save.png"), "Save the image",KeyEvent.VK_S);
```

The error is due to this :

`KeyEvent.VK_S` must be an `int` and not `Integer` and you have `Integer` as the last argument. So try changing it or just cast it as `new Integer(KeyEvent.VK_S)`

Answer (score 0):

```
Action saveAction = new SaveAction("Save", new ImageIcon("img/save.png"), "Save the image",
KeyEvent.VK_S);
```

Is the form you're calling the method, but, notice that your constructor:

```
public SaveAction(String text, ImageIcon icon, String desc, Integer mnemonic)
```

KeyEvent.VK_S returns an int which is a primitive type. Your constructor expects a class Integer which is like an int but, as you can see, it is not a primitive type, it is a class which has methods and attributes. So then you can invoke your constructor as this:

```
Action saveAction = new SaveAction("Save", new ImageIcon("img/save.png"), "Save the image",
    new Integer(KeyEvent.VK_S)));
```

Answer (score 0):

Your constructor needs an Integer object, not the int primitive. In contrast to the other solutions I would advise you to use `Integer.valueOf` instead of `new Integer`, especially as KeyEvent.VK_S will always represent the same int value:

```
Action saveAction = new SaveAction("Save", new ImageIcon("img/save.png"), "Save the image", Integer.valueOf(KeyEvent.VK_S)));
```

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2974561/new-integer-vs-valueof) for more details.