# How can two wrapper objects be equal, yet not equal at the same time

Tags: java, integer, comparison

I have this code:

```
class ABC
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Integer inta = new Integer(10);
        Integer intb = new Integer(10);
        if (inta <= intb) {
            System.out.println("inta is less than intb");
        }
        if (inta >= intb) {
            System.out.println("inta is greater than intb");
        }
        if (inta != intb) {
            System.out.println("inta is not equal to intb");
        }
    }
}
```

This outputs:

```
inta is less than intb
inta is greater than intb
inta is not equal to intb
```

Can anyone explain why this happens? How can an object be equal and not equal at the same time?

Comment: You could also try with `Integer inta = 10; Integer intb = 10;` and you will get different results.

Comment: @ColeJohnson This has nothing to do with the cache.

Comment: @assylias I tried with it and got following output                   inta is less than intb
inta is greater than intb

Comment: `<=` is "less than or equal to", and `>=` is "greater than or equal to". And == checks if they're the same object, which they're not. Use compareTo() and check the value returned from that instead.

Comment: @cole isn't that what op is doing and getting false? I think you misunderstood where the cache applies.

Comment: @Sotirios I probably do misunderstand it because I avoid the wrapper classes at all costs in my programming.

Comment: To elaborate on splrs' comment, your code is working as you've told it to. Instead of `>=` and `<=`, you should be using `>` and `<`, and `.equals()` or `.compareTo()` instead of `==`. The first two conditions you have are always satisfied because 10 always **equals** 10. The last condition is always `false` because `inta` and `intb` are two distinct object **references**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrapper objects are still objects; if one performs object equivalence on them (`==`), then unless they're the exact same reference, that will always be `false`.

Unboxing happens because we're using [relational operators](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.20), which will unbox to a type that can be respected by the operators - in this case, `int`.  The comparison happens as if you didn't have the wrappers.

Things get interesting if you use the fact that [`Integer` can be cached](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2974568/1079354) through the use of `valueOf()`.

If your expression appeared as such:

```
Integer inta = Integer.valueOf(10);
Integer intb = Integer.valueOf(10);
```

...then performing `inta == intb` would equal `true`, since both values are between the cached range of [-128, 127].

Since you're attempting to see if a value is larger than, greater than, or equal to another, then consider using [`Comparable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) instead.  An `Integer` is a `Comparable` entity, so you can simply do this:

```
System.out.println(inta.compareTo(intb) < 0); // to check for a < b
System.out.println(inta.compareTo(intb) == 0); // to check for a == b
System.out.println(inta.compareTo(intb) > 0); // to check for a > b
```

Answer (score 2):

It satisfies the first and second ones because the compiler needs primitive types for greater-than (`>`) or less-than comparison (`<`) operations, so it makes an auto unboxing from `Integer` to `int`. Because you use the or-equal-to operators (`<=` and `>=`), the conditional is true.

It satisfies the third one because the compiler checks two `Integer` object to see if they are the same object, and since they are not, the conditional is true.

Answer (score 0):

Use `inta.compareTo(intb)` and check the value returned.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#compareTo%28java.lang.Integer%29

e.g.

```
int res = inta.compareTo(intb);
if (res < 0)
{
    System.out.println("inta is less than intb");
}
if (res > 0)
{
    System.out.println("inta is greater than intb");
}
if (res != 0)
{
    System.out.println("inta is not equal to intb");
}
```

To repeat my comment on the OP: The operators used in the first two tests are incorrect, as they test "less and *or equal to*" and "greater than *or equal to*", and changing those to < and > would work for those as the underlying int is unboxed in those cases. However, == is checking whether they're the same object, which they're not, so it will return `false` unless you have something like `inta == inta`.