# How can we know the size of Integer Class Object?

Tags: java, object, integer

How can we judge the size of Integer Class Object ? for example : Integer i = new Integer(10); so in the above case what is the size of 'i'. Does it valid ??

Comment: What programming language? What do you mean by "size"?

Comment: Related to Java .Size here indicate how much memory does Integer Object occupy at runtime .

Comment: Depending on the scenario, it could be zero (enregistered), or it could be very large (boxed). Why does it matter to you?

Comment: See this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/52353/in-java-what-is-the-best-way-to-determine-the-size-of-an-object

Comment: Writing `new Integer(10)` is [probably a bad idea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2974561/new-integer-vs-valueof).  Especially if you are concerned about memory usage.  Use `Integer.valueOf(10)` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Java has a pool of Integer constants between -128 and 128. Integer values in that range don't take up any additional space.

Integer values outside that range take as much space as an object header + 4 bytes. How big that is depends on your JVM and settings. Look at http://sourceforge.net/projects/sizeof or https://code.google.com/p/memory-measurer if you want to programmatically measure the size.

Edit: Note that `Integer i = new Integer(10);` will **not** use the object constant pool. That's why you should always use `Integer.valueOf(x)` instead of `new Integer(x)` when instantiating. Note also that autoboxing already does the right thing, so `Integer i = 10` will also use the constant pool.