# Need help for Generic comparison method

Tags: java, generics

I am learning generic methods in Java. I want to count number of elements of an array greater than a given number. Here is my code:

```
public class GenericMethodExample {
    public interface Comparable<T>{
        public int compareTo(T o);
    }

    public static <T extends Comparable<T>> int countGreaterThan(T[] list, T element){
        int count = 0;
        for(T e:list){
            if (e.compareTo(element)>0){
                ++count;
            }
        }
        return count;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        Integer[] intArray = {5 ,10,8,1,0,3};
        Integer u = new Integer(5);
        System.out.print("Number of elements are greater than "+ u.toString()+" is:");
        System.out.print(countGreaterThan(intArray,u));
    }
}
```

I got error  "countGreaterThan is not applicable for the arguments (Integer[],Integer)". How could I change my code?

Thanks.

Comment: why do you need Comparable interface defined in your class? There is already one in java APIs

Comment: Apart from your actual problem, instead of new Integer(5), use Integer.valueOf(5). http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2974561/new-integer-vs-valueof

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't write `Comparable` interface by yourself, it's the default Java interface from `java.lang` package (you don't even have to import in manually). Remove your interface declaration inside class and it will work:

```
public class GenericMethodExample {

    public static <T extends Comparable<T>> int countGreaterThan(T[] list, T element){
        int count = 0;
        for(T e:list){
            if (e.compareTo(element)>0){
                ++count;
            }
        }
        return count;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        Integer[] intArray = {5 ,10,8,1,0,3};
        Integer u = new Integer(5);
        System.out.print("Number of elements are greater than "+ u.toString()+" is:");
        System.out.print(countGreaterThan(intArray,u));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your method `countGreaterThan` is for types that extends your own `Comparable` interface. `Integer` doesn't but extends the build in `java.lang.Comparable` interface. So remove your interface and it works or use it with an own class that extends your interface.